# Javascript click on coordinates inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, click

I have searched some things about click on coordinates with javascript and 
i have found that this line of code helps you click on x,y coordinates

```
document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
```

So when i put the width and height of an html element or a button it clicks it good and it redirects me to the page that i want.

But when i have an iframe html object (like a google ad)  it doesnt work.
I cant understand why though because i think "click()" is like simulating a normal mouse click... or am I wrong with this?

I have read that iframe has a protection that you cant go inside the html elements but all i'm trying to figure out is how to simulate a normal click on the iframe.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously prohibited due to security issues.

If it was possible to programmatically trigger a click event within an iframe, you could trigger certain actions on behalf of the user visiting your page. You could for example open your own twitter account in an iframe -- the visitor of your page logged in -- and let the user follow you with a click on the follow button. You can certainly think of more critical examples...

Basically, you could take over all accounts the user is logged in with a cookie. You can open any web page in an iframe and act on behalf of the logged in user by simulating click or keyboard events.

Comment: I don't understand your logic. Thought i was clear of what i'm trying to do.

Comment: I updated the answer. I hope now it becomes clear what I mean.